# RVM installation MacOS Mavericks

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

Hi there I can't install rvm on my mac (Mavericks 10.9.2) after:

```
curl -sSL -k https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

I get output:

```
Unknown option: n
Unknown option: 1
Usage: head [-options] <url>...
-m <method>   use method for the request (default is 'HEAD')
-f            make request even if head believes method is illegal
-b <base>     Use the specified URL as base
-t <timeout>  Set timeout value
-i <time>     Set the If-Modified-Since header on the request
-c <conttype> use this content-type for POST, PUT, CHECKIN
-a            Use text mode for content I/O
-p <proxyurl> use this as a proxy
-P            don't load proxy settings from environment
-H <header>   send this HTTP header (you can specify several)

-u            Display method and URL before any response
-U            Display request headers (implies -u)
-s            Display response status code
-S            Display response status chain
-e            Display response headers
-d            Do not display content
-o <format>   Process HTML content in various ways

-v            Show program version
-h            Print this message

-x            Extra debugging output
BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 3.2.51(1)-release)
```

Downgrading bash for me is meaningless any hint how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 8):

In my case this problem was caused by the order of PATH entries in *.bash_profile*. `/usr/bin/head` (expected by rvm installer) was overridden by `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/head` which seems to do something different. Switching the order to something like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! That error was driving me nuts.